# Java DeflaterInputStream() to ZlibInflation

Tags: java, c++, zlib, deflate

I'm currently working on a project that involves compression and encryption in java, and decryption and inflation in C++.

Prior to what I was working on, we were creating compressed files using the ZipOutputStream in java. These files will inflate with zlib in the C++ just fine using the zpipe.c code given as an example on ZLib. Our latest shift was to compress these files and then encrypt before storing in the parent zip. In doing this, I have switched to using the DeflaterInputStream class in Java to arbitrarily compress bytes until I have enough for the block cipher.

In switching to this "DeflaterInputStream" class, the files will no longer inflate using ZLib. Zlib is throwing a "Z_DATA_ERROR" on the stream.

To verify thus far I have verified the crypto logic is valid. I can inflate the files just fine in java using the "Inflater" class. Both inflater classes begin with just a single decrypted block. Ex. I have verified that the first block that comes out of the cipher is the same for both the Java and the C++. To me it appears like the DeflaterInputStream is not outputting a true deflate format? I'm not sure.

EDIT: To clarify my specific implementation
Example Pseduo Code:

Java (Working with zpipe)

```
FileOutputStream dest = new FileOutputStream("zipfile.zip");
ZipOutputStream out = new ZipOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(dest));

ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry("filename");
out.putNextEntry(entry);

FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream("file_to_compress");

byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
int bytesRead;
while ((bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buf)) > 0) {
    out.write(buf, 0, bytesRead);
}
out.closeEntry();
out.close();
fileInputStream.close();
```

Java (Not Working with zpipe)

```
FileOutputStream dest = new FileOutputStream("zipfile.zip");
ZipOutputStream out = new ZipOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(dest));

DeflaterInputStream deflater = new DeflaterInputStream("file_to_compress");

/* Redacted code to compress file, encrypt, write to file and calculate CRC 
Assume encryptedFile is a reference to the result of this process */


ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry("filename");
entry.setCrc32(encryptedFile.getCrc32());
entry.setCompressedSize(encryptedFile.getLength());
entry.setMethod(ZipEntry.STORED); /* Should not try to compress encrypted file*/

out.putNextEntry(entry);
byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
int bytesRead;
while ((bytesRead = encryptedFile.read(buf)) > 0) {
    out.write(buf, 0, bytesRead);
}
out.closeEntry();
encryptedFile.close();
out.close();
```

So pretty much I'm using the DeflaterInputStream to compress a fixed size to feed into the cipher and then store in the archive. I have it working end to end inside the java by taking the results of DeflaterInputStream and cipher and writing to file, then decrypting to a plaintext buffer and using the Inflater class to process that. It is my understanding that both the Inflater and DeflaterInputStream classes handle a raw deflate stream without accounting for or adding any sort of archive header. We're using our own code in the C++ to parse the archive headers and whatnot to feed into zpipe.

I expect Zlib/Zpipe to be able to process the raw stream I create using the DeflaterInputStream the same as if I compressed using a generic ZipEntry/ZipOutputStream object instead.

Ever since I have tried to use the DeflaterInputStream, zlib/zpipe is throwing an error when trying to read the stream.

**UPDATE**

To troubleshoot futher I did the following:

Saved the raw output of DeflaterInputStream compressing a file.

Used the same file in a ZipOutputStream/ZipEntry pairing to create a compressed zip archive.

Used a Hex Editor to delete the local file headers and central directory of the archive, leaving only the raw deflate stream.

Ran the edited file (raw deflate stream) through zpipe: Worked

Ran the DeflaterInputStream output through zpipe: Not working

**UPDATE 2**

So I just compared the output of the two.
DeflaterInputStream is giving me two extra bytes at the start of the stream. I have no clue what these bytes are. If I skip over them with fseek() the file decompresses just fine. The values are 0x78 0x9C of these mysterious bytes...

**UPDATE 3**

I have been referencing RFC 1951 throughout this process, however, it looks like the magic two bytes comes from RFC 1950. Was misled by the name "DeflaterInputStream".

Initializing DeflaterInputStream with the following solves my issue:

```
Deflater def = new Deflater(Deflater.DEFAULT_COMPRESSION,true);
DeflaterInputStream defIfs = new DeflaterInputStream(ifs,def);
```

Big thanks to Mark for giving this question a look over! Zlib is a beautiful project.

Comment: `ZipOutputStream` produces output in the zip format. Not the zlib, gzip, or raw deflate format, so it would not be decompressible with zpipe. Your initial premise makes no sense.

Comment: Sorry I oversimplified. Yes ZipOutputStream creates the local file header and CD information for the parent Zip object, however, the stream itself should be compressed with the deflate format. We were using the ZipOutputStream to write to the zip file directly, however, this should be equivalent to using the deflaterstream, calculating the CRC and file size, and storing in the archive without compression.

Comment: I remain unclear on what you're trying. Please correct your question to say exactly what you're doing, what you had expected to happen, and what is actually happening instead.

Comment: Ahh sorry for the confusion. I really appreciate the follow up! I added some more to my original post to hopefully clarify things. Thanks for any feedback / advice you can give.

Comment: What the heck do you mean by "working with zpipe"? The result of that Java code is a _zip_ file, which zpipe cannot process.

Comment: At the end of the code I gave a breif description. We have minizip equivalent code written to parse the archive header and feed the offset from the CD and local header of the start of the deflate stream directly to zpipe.

Comment: The problem appears that the compressed file of the resulting archive is in a different format between  "ZipEntry" and "DeflaterInputStream" classes.

Comment: By working with Zpipe here's what I mean:

Java will create the zip archive.

Inside the archive are the deflate streams. These streams are allegedly compressed using the deflate format according to java. 

The archive will have headers and a directory indicating where these streams start.

The C++ will:

Parse the archive headers to find the start of the desired file.
Decrypt the compressed file, then feed zpipe.